# using python to draw a line star like pattern

Tags: python, python-3.5

[the pattern picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9KnX.png)

I'm trying to draw the pattern at the right but I'm finding it difficult 
please check my codes

```
from graphics import *
win=GraphWin("STAR",100,100)
for i in range(0,100,10):
    for j in range(0,100,10):
        p1=Point(100-i,0+j)
        p2=Point(0+i,100-j)
        line=Line(p1,p2)
        line.draw(win)
```

Comment: Why not use the turtle module?

Comment: it is a uni work, i have to use graphics module. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from graphics import *
win=GraphWin("STAR",100,100)
for i in range(0,100,10):
    p1=Point(0,i)
    p2=Point(100,100-i)
    line=Line(p1,p2)
    line.draw(win)
    p1=Point(100-i,0)
    p2=Point(i,100)
    line=Line(p1,p2)
    line.draw(win)
```

if you think about the starting point of all the rays you only need to think of the left edge and the top.

You will only need to step through the loop once and draw a line from `(x,0)` to `(100,100-x)` then a line from the y transform of those points.

Comment: thank you so much, really appreciate it.